# Search by SKU not working in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, search, sku, advanced-search, search-terms

I am facing some problems while searching with SKU in the catalog search.

I have already turned on "Use in Search" and "Visible in Advanced Search" fields for SKU product attribute. However, when I search using SKU it's not showing any results.

I have tried the advanced search and an extension both of them are returning no results.

Does anyone know what to do, please help.

Comment: what searchengine are you using? die you reindex after changing the values?

Comment: I am using the MySQL Search Engine and I did reindex a couple of times.